# I think I screwed up my file directory while trouble-shooting in jupyter notebook/python3

Tags: python-3.x, bash, path, jupyter-notebook

I'm not sure exactly where to start with this question, but I am relatively new to python and have mostly been working with Jupyter notebook & Python 3.7.

After working/trouble-shooting my way through a number of problems (particularly setting up a virtual environment and installing packages to that environment) I seem to have screwed up my file directory.

What's particularly troubling is I can't launch jupyter notebook from my base(root), instead I get the following text displayed in terminal:

```
    Last login: Sun Dec 22 21:02:15 on ttys000
    /Users/*********/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
    -bash: dirname: command not found
    -bash: dirname: command not found
    -bash: /etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
    -bash: conda: command not found
    ********-MacBook-Pro:~ *********$ /Users/********/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
    /Users/********/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 1: dirname: command not found
    /Users/********/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 3: /jupyter-notebook: No such file or directory
    logout
    Saving session...
    ...copying shared history...
    ...saving history...truncating history files...
    ...completed.

    [Process completed]
```

Above, my name has redacted.

On the other hand, if I open a blank terminal window, I am prompted with:

```
Last login: Sun Dec 22 20:54:30 on ttys000
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: /etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: conda: command not found
********-MacBook-Pro:~ ********$
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated! I am going to try to do a system update tonight to see if that resolves anything in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have changed your `.bash_profile` and removed `/usr/bin` from PATH (which is where `dirname` and other commands are located) and perhaps other things too.

Check the content of `$PATH`:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

and restore whatever seems missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the conda environment is wrong on your Mac.
Can you try the next one?

1. open terminal
2. type 
   source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
3. type
   conda init
4. restart terminal
5. try jupyter notebook again